Impact of lexicographic order in sorting a multi-dimensional list
I am learning python at basic level. I have a confusion over the impact & application of lexicographic order in sorting a multi-dimensional list. It will be so kind, if any respected seniors help me out. Thank You!
a = [[10, 1], [200, 2], [2, 4]]
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[0])
print(b)  # Output: [[2, 4], [10, 1], [200, 2]]

Python sorts lists lexicographically (correct me if I get it wrong).
Lexicographic order is [10, 2, 200] than why in the output of the code sublist started with 2 comes before 10?

Does this answer your question? What is lexicographical order?

In the given example the sorting is done by the value of the first item in a sub-list (as int). Lexicographic sorting example would be something like: sorted(a, key=lambda sublist:" ".join(str(value) for value in sublist))

Python sorts STRINGS lexicographically.  There is no confusion on how to sort integers, which is what your lists are.  2 is less than 10, but comparing the strings "2" and "10" can have different meanings.
